# How to allows songs to be rearrange in playlists using Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have created a core data model like below

[Songs Core Data Attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FguTm.png)

[Songs Core Data Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3grAS.png)

[Playlists Core Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzjT2.png)

I have use this as code to pull from Core Data and arrange it with Alphabetical order.

```
let PlaylistTable = (PlaylistTables![0] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "songs") as! NSSet

let songsUnsorted = PlaylistTable.allObjects as NSArray
return songsUnsorted.sortedArray(using: [songSortDescriptor]) as NSArray
```

How can i do to allows songs to be rearrange in the order i like ? Example

```
a
b
c
```

To whatever arrangement i like and next time when i pull from Core Data it will be the same order ?

```
b
c
a
```

Comment: not sure but maybe using `NSMutableOrderedSet` for the attribute in the Playlist class and its relationship in the xcdatamodel to ordered could be a good start ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an attribute that will function as an index. That way, when you fetch, you ask for a sort descriptor that sorts on that attribute.